# how to print string at the end of the previous string Python

Tags: python, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to print in Python without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space)
>   [How to print a string without including ‘\n’ in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511204/how-to-print-a-string-without-including-n-in-python)

I have a code that looks like this:

```
  print 'Going to %s'%href
            try:
                self.opener.open(self.url+href)
                print 'OK'
```

When I execute it I get two lines obviously:

```
Going to mysite.php
OK
```

But want is :

```
Going to mysite.php OK
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> def test():
...    print 'let\'s',
...    pass
...    print 'party'
... 
>>> test()
let's party
>>>
```

for your example:

```
# note the comma at the end
print 'Going to %s' % href,
try:
   self.opener.open(self.url+href)
   print 'OK'
except:
   print 'ERROR'
```

the [comma at the end](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement) of the print statement instructs to not add a `'\n'` newline character.

I assumed this question was for python 2.x because `print` is used as a statement. For python 3 you need to specify `end=''` to the print function call:

```
# note the comma at the end
print('Going to %s' % href, end='')
try:
   self.opener.open(self.url+href)
   print(' OK')
except:
   print(' ERROR')
```

Comment: Seems to doesn't work with python 3 : http://pastie.org/5054695

Comment: I assumed from the question that this was not python 3. let me include that.

Comment: found out that this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-in-python-without-newline-or-space

Answer (score 2):

In python3 you have to set the `end` argument (that defaults to `\n`) to empty string:

```
print('hello', end='')
```

http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#print

Answer (score 1):

Use comma at the end of your first `print`: -

```
print 'Going to %s'%href,
```